# TCP client-server error in transmitting edittext

Tags: java, android, sockets, tcp

I have here my code:

```
 private Button.OnClickListener get_view_button_listener = new Button.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
          String r = "";
          if (chxbx1.isChecked()) {
            r = r + "\n" + chxbx1.getText() + ".............." + txtbox1.getText().toString();

          }
          if (chxbx2.isChecked()) {
            r = r + "\n" + chxbx2.getText() + ".............." + txtbox2.getText().toString();

          }
          if (chxbx3.isChecked()) {
            r = r + "\n" + chxbx3.getText() + ".............." + txtbox3.getText().toString();

          }
          if (chxbx4.isChecked()) {
            r = r + "\n" + chxbx4.getText() + ".............." + txtbox4.getText().toString();

          }
          kaboom.setText(r);


                  }


      };
```

What I want is the product of this will be my input that is to be transmitted to my server via socket TCP. Can any of you please help me?

Comment: please clarify your question, and what is `kaboom`?

Comment: @raffian kaboom is an edittext. That 'chxbx's will perform a mathematical operation. And it will output for about 4 lines of text. And I want that 4 lines of text to be my input that is to be send to my server via TCP sockets.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) [The official Java SE Tutorial website](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/index.html) has a good walkthrough on how to do client server socket programming

Comment: I get the string that holds the result of those. But when I link it on my server and asynctask, it crashes.